# LBP(local binary patterns) for 6x6 cells using 16 bit image

Tags: image-processing, lbph-algorithm

I have done LBP feature implementation for each pixel position in 3x3 pixel cell by:
Generate the 4-bit binary state values
Reduce the 16 states to 8 states according to lookup table
Count the occurrence of the 8 bins.

I want to implement the same for 16bit input image by using 6x6 pixel cell, since there is no mid point for 6x6 pixel cell I cannot implement this similar to 3x3. Can any one give me an idea how can i start with this implementation.
Appreciated in advance for the advice.

Comment: i think the neighborhood that you use for LBP has to be with odd size because the calculation is with regard to the middle pixel.

Comment: Thanks @AmitayNachmani, Cant we do lbp for each pixel in 6x6 with there neighborhood then the count of iterations will be 36*4(since 6x6 is 36 pixel cell and 4 is the lbp comparison for 3x3) so i want to implement lbp for each pixel with its neighbor 3x3.

Comment: Ok now i understand. I will think about that and try to give you answer.

Comment: @AmitayNachmani Thank you.